# What is the effect of parentheses on pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

For example, what is the difference between

```
(*user1).id
```

and

```
*user1.id
```

It would be much better to have a example to explain.
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. `(*user1).id` dereferences `user1`, which must be a pointer to a structure containing an `id` field, and gets the `id` field out of that structure.  100% equivalent to `user1->id`.
2. `*user1.id` gets field `id` out of `user1` which must be a structure (not a pointer to a structure) contaning an `id` field.  It then dereferences that value, meaning the `id` field must have a pointer type.

All of this is simple [C operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B).  The `.` (element selection by reference) operator has higher precedence than the `*` (indirection/dereference) operator.

Answer (score 4):

Without parentheses, the . (dot) operator has precedence over (ie. binds closer than) the * operator. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

The parentheses in this example binds the lower precedence operator first.

```
*user1.id
```

is equivalent to:

```
*(user1.id)   The * operator dereferences .id, which if .id is not a pointer, is illegal syntax
```

Different from

```
(*user1).id   The * operator dereferences user1, which must be a pointer, to get the id member
```

The parse tree reductions look something like:

```
    (*user1).id
    member_expression
    ( struct_expression )              DOT member
    ( pointer_expression )             DOT member
    ( DEREFERENCE_OP IDENTIFIER )      DOT member )
    ( DEREFERENCE_OP IDENTIFIER )      DOT IDENTIFIER )
```

vs.

```
    *user1.id 
    DEREFERENCE_OP user1.id
    DEREFERENCE_OP ( member_expression )
    DEREFERENCE_OP ( struct_expression DOT member )
    DEREFERENCE_OP ( IDENTIFIER        DOT member )
    DEREFERENCE_OP ( IDENTIFIER        DOT IDENTIFIER )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could see + - how it looks like, in first one **(in the image below)** you need to have user declared as:

```
    user user1;
```

and make sure that the field **id** is a pointer, because thats what you are dereferencing!

In the second one you must have declared like:

```
    user* user1;
```

Here **id** have any type

[image]